# Story with dome-cities and the last horse being lost in transport accident

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, dystopia, animals

I read some of a story in high school in Quebec, probably a bit more than 10 years ago (before 2008). I think I might have read it as part of a reading test at school. It was probably in French (might have been a translation), but it's possible that it was part of the English class. I believe they may have presented us just a short chapter of a whole book for the test. The original might be a book or a short story. I think I probably read a photocopy of some pages only.

I think the story is set on Earth, maybe in the future. One character, maybe the main, is a young-ish woman. Her father is also present in the story. Unfortunately, I don't recall the characters' names. They live in a dome city, and there are other domes on the world. Outside of the dome the world is like a desert, or in a post-apocalyptic condition.

The young woman (and possibly her father) are either witnessing an event that is publicly broadcast on TV or are looking at it through a window.

The last horse on earth is being transported from one dome to another. It is mentioned that the girl never saw an animal before, she only saw them in books. It might be one of the last animals in the whole world.
An accident happens and something breaks as the horse is being tubed between the two domes. I think the horse actually falls in the outside "wasteland". Whether the horse dies in the accident or is seen running away into the wilderness I don't remember.

I know there are a lot of dome-city stories out there, hopefully the horse-incident should help to find exactly the one.

I remember really liking this story and I always wished to read the whole piece, this small chapter was not enough for me! Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

I think the domes were see-through. About the connection between two domes for transport of the horse, I'm not sure. It might a been a kind of tube between the two, or some mobile container (not quite a vehicle) that made the transit between the two. I don't remember if the transit happened on ground level or above, but I tend to think it was above.

Comment: There is [The Flight of the Horse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flight_of_the_Horse) by Larry Niven, part of the Svetz series, but it involves time travel instead of a simple mechanical transfer.

Comment: @Spencer That was a cool read, but that's not the one I'm looking for